# Match only a character between two others

Tags: python, regex

I try to replace a "/" with a "-" in regex an Python, but only the one between capital letters and a number:

```
data["image_cloud"] = re.sub(r"[A-Z]+(/*)[0-9]", "-", data["image_cloud"])
```

With this regex, it selects all the characters, not only the "/"

Comment: Correct regex to use is `(?<=[A-Z])/*(?=\d)`

Comment: Try `data["image_cloud"] = data["image_cloud"].str.replace(r"([A-Z])/([0-9])", r"\1-\2")`

Comment: If you have an answer, you should write it up as an answer :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thank you very much, your solution works great !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working with `pandas`, so, use `str.replace` like:

```
data["image_cloud"] = data["image_cloud"].str.replace(r"([A-Z])/([0-9])", r"\1-\2")
```

In `([A-Z])/([0-9])`, `([A-Z])` is the capturing group #1 that matches an uppercase letter and `([0-9])` is the capturing group #2 that captures a digit, and `\1` and `\2` are their corresponding backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Mind the `r` prefix that denotes a *raw* string literal.

Answer (score 0):

following what you say, the right pattern is:

```
data["image_cloud"] = re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z])/(?=\d)", "-", data["image_cloud"])

  AZ/09 will be replaced by AZ-09
  AZ09 will not be replaced
```

be care if you use:

```
data["image_cloud"] = re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z])/*(?=\d)", "-", data["image_cloud"])

  AZ/09 will be replaced by AZ-09
  AZ09 will be replaced by AZ-09 (also)
```